# Django Mongo Integration

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django-mongo/) to integrate Mongo with Django. I was successfully able to integrate but I've few doubts.

**1)** When I use a normal MySQL table in Django, and then fire a `syncdb` command, then some additional table in Django are built, which I require for setting permissions using `auth_group_permissions`.

**2)** integrate Mongo so that authentication is backed by MongoDB (i.e. the default User model) as well as the sessions thing.

**3)** Django admin is also blocked(as read in this tutorial).

Point **3)** is not actually needed but **(1) and (2)** are needed for certain.

How should I get it into Mongo?

Comment: It's worth considering to run Django on MySQL and other data on MongoDB.

Comment: Is it actually recommended?

Comment: I mean using multiple DB's (mongo,mysql) in one project?

Comment: Well, the basic models of Django work well on MySQL and there's no reason to complicate things. MongoDB would work well in certain cases but I don't see why you'd want all of Django to run on MongoDB.

Comment: I've not yet implemented, so things are still simple, yet complicated.  I'm actually acquiring some information before taking a step. So, you mean to say I should use both MySQL and Mongo in 1 project? Is it recommended?

Comment: Are you tied to Mongo in some way. If you use PostgreSql you can use it for both SQL and noSQL (through hstore, see http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2012/06/11/schemaless-django/). You won't end up running/maintaining two database instances. Als, PostgreSql is the preferred solution over Mysql.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Yes, I actually have my data stored in Mongo. I'm making a Big Data application for which I'm using Mongo to store my data, and then I need to show the information stored in Mongo onto the UI. Hence, the answer is Yes that I'm tied to Mongo.